# Set sprite width or height without scaling it's children

Tags: actionscript-3, size, sprite, scale

I am trying to dynamically change the `width` and `height` of a Sprite object, which is a container for other similar Sprite objects. The container object automatically changes it's size according to the size of it's children, but when I change the position of the children objects, the size of the container stays the same and it's children appear to be placed outside of the container.

I tried to solve this problem by using something like this:

```
if (container.width < (child.x + child.width))
{
    container.width = (child.x + child.width);
}
```

But when I use this code, the container object's children are scaled.
Is there a way to change the container's size without scaling it's children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible directly, the size of a sprite depends on the bounds of its contents. So the only option would be to resize a child of the sprite, or place a dummy child on `x: 0`, `y: 0` *(assuming this would be your desired anchor point)*.

The coordinates of the contents bounds is not taken into account as you might expect, when having for example one child that is `100 x 100px`, placed on `x: 50, y: 50`, the parents size would still be `100 x 100px`, not `150 x 150px`.

Adding another child of `100 x 100px` on `x: 0, y: 0` would increase the bounds to `150 x 150`, because it now starts on child one `x: 0, y: 0` and ends on child two `x: 50, y: 50` + `100 x 100px`.

[image: content bounds]

Comment: ok, thanks. so I pretty much have to add another child to the container, of which I set the width and height? seems simple enough.